# Positive definite symmetric matrix satisfying a certain property concerning a group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> We have a finite group $G$ and a homomorphism $\rho: G \rightarrow \mathbb{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ where $n$ is a positive integer. I need to show that there's an $n\times n$ positive definite symmetric matrix that satisfies $\rho(g)^tA\rho(g)=A$ for all $g \in G$, where $t$ means the transpose.

So far, all I could do was write definitions...not sure where to start. So for all non-zero vectors $v$ with $n$ real entries, $v^tAv>0$, and I know $A=A^t$ Also, I know $A$ is positive-definite if and only if there exists an invertible $n\times n$ matrix $P$ such that $A=P^tP$. But I'm not really sure where to go with that. I was wondering maybe I can start with $\rho(g)^tA\rho(g)=A$ and then show that $A$ is positive-definite, but I don't really see that going anywhere.

Comment: [Some people have the same homework.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587932/existence-of-a-g-invariant-matrix/588740#588740)